# odbc connection and oracle server connection in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Please suggest what is the difference between odbc connection and oracle server connection in crystal reports while connecting to oracle database.

Please suggest when we will use both of them

Answer (score 0):

ODBC works with "rectangular" or 2D data. If you have spatial data, you will need to use the native Oracle client. Our DBA also says Oracle ODBC has to convert data types while a native client would be "apples to apples".

If you have a Crystal Server accessing an Oracle database, use the native Oracle client. On your workstation, also run the same client whether ODBC or Native as the server.